# R: error message --- package error: "functionName" not resolved from current namespace

Tags: r

I am using a package that has worked up until R3.0.

the issue is as above .... when we call a function that works in R 2.15.2 
from  R 3.0 we get an error

```
Error in .C("solarspectrum3", as.double(lon), as.double(lat), as.double(timezone),  : 
  "solarspectrum3" not resolved from current namespace (SolarSpectrum)
```

any help would be appreciated

Alex

The package could be found at https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgspdzd2rq5jmh6/SolarSpectrum_1.0.tar.gz

install the package

R CMD INSTALL SolarSpectrum_1.0.tar.gz
, then

run

`require(SolarSpectrum)`

`longitude=2`

`latitude=50`

`date=as.POSIXct("2008-06-06")`

`PAR <- SolarSpectrum.PAR(longitude, latitude, date)[2]`

The error should show up at this time

Comment: Did you reinstall all packages as instructed when you installed R 3.0.0?

Comment: -1 Which package? Which function? Reproducible example?

Comment: Yes I reinstall the package. The package is SolarSpectrum. It is not accessible from the R-cran Repositery

Comment: The package: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgspdzd2rq5jmh6/SolarSpectrum_1.0.tar.gz

Answer (score 6):

This error message can affect functions that call external code using calls to [`.C()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/Foreign) or [`.Call()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/CallExternal).

The problem is described well in [this R-help thread](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/question-re-error-message-package-error-quot-functionName-quot-not-resolved-from-current-namespace-td4663892.html); in particular Martin Morgan's response is useful. He quotes an entry to R's `NEWS` file, when version 3.0.0 was released.

> A foreign function call (.C() etc) in a package without a PACKAGE
>   argument will only look in the first DLL specified in the NAMESPACE
>   file of the package rather than searching all loaded DLLs.  A few
>   packages needed PACKAGE arguments added.

So the call to `.C()` or `.Call()` needs to be amended in the package's source, to include `PACKAGE = "name_of_dll_without_extension"`.

You can find the DLL names with the following code.

```
dir(system.file("libs", package = "rpkgname"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may have been solved by now; however, try setting the PACKAGE argument for the .C call in SolarSpectrum.PAR to "SolarSpectrum" (this may involve altering the package source files for SolarSpectrum.PAR). That may get R to look in the correct namespace (I haven't actually tried this, but it worked for a different package with the same error).