# R Leaps Package: Regsubsets - coef "Reordr" Fortran error

Tags: r

I'm using the R `leaps` package to obtain a fit to some data:
(My dataframe `df` contains a `Y` variable and 41 predictor variables)

```
require(leaps) 
N=3
regsubsets(Y ~ ., data = df, nbest=1, nvmax=N+1,force.in="X", method = 'exhaustive')-> regfit

coef(regfit,id = N)
```

When I run the code more than once (the first time works fine) I get the following error when I run the coef command:

> Error in .Fortran("REORDR", np = as.integer(object$np), nrbar = as.integer(object$nrbar),  : 
>     "reordr" not resolved from current namespace (leaps)

Any help with why this is happening would be much appreciated.
A.

Answer (score 0):

I had to build the package from source inserting the (PACKAGE = 'leaps') argument into the REORDR function in the leaps.R file. It now works fine every time.

The solution is related to:

[R: error message --- package error: "functionName" not resolved from current namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192225/r-error-message-package-error-functionname-not-resolved-from-current-nam)